# WebGL parameter types

Tags: typescript, webgl

There appear to be several conflicts between WebGL documentation and official typescript definitions - as well as conflicts in the docs themselves.

Take for example `gl.pixelStorei`.

The MDN docs[1] state that `param` is a `GLint`.

This is also confirmed in the Typescript dom definitions[2].

However - if we look at the table of allowed values, we see that there are other allowed types. In fact searches on the web find that it's common to call  `gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true)` - i.e. with `true`, not `1`.

Can someone please explain what's going on here? This is particularly troubling with a typescript build which *fails* due to errors when using a `boolean` for functions that require a `GLint`.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/pixelStorei

[2] https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L15739

Comment: Looks like the specific case of `gl.pixelStorei` is being addressed in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27542).  What other problems did you find?  You could check if they already have open issues.

Comment: Oh, thanks... tbh I just saw a whole bunch of errors and didn't pay much attention to them in detail, will check it out and file if needed. Though the MDN docs are also confusing since it says the parameter is a GLint